# I wonder if the PP tense in some (or all) of these sentences is either optional or mandatory or wrong

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

> Yesterday I watched the movie “Father”. I hadn’t expected it, but the
> movie proved to be a masterpiece. This morning I was surprised to
> learn that the 93d Oscar ceremony had been held last night, and
> Hopkins had won an Oscar for the main role.

Is the past perfect tense in some (or all) of these sentences either optional or mandatory or wrong?

Comment: It all seems fine to me.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. But I think it would also be fine with ***I didn't expect it,... the ceremony was held last night,... Hopkins won an Oscar***. And I always say if you don't know you *need* Past Perfect, don't use it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Your third sentence goes "This morning I was surprised to learn the 93rd Oscar ceremony was held last night, and Hopkins won..." **Bit shoddy**, I'd say, compared with the OP's version.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: You'd get on well with TEFL teachers then. To my mind, the difference is most TEFL teachers actively seek out opportunities to use Perfect verb forms (to prove they know how to use them?), whereas I tend to look for ways to *avoid* Perfect forms. I have no idea where *most* native speakers stand on this one, but I suspect that in practice many of those who side with me (in terms of their *actual* speech production) might deny this because of half-remembered "rules" from their school days. I might ask on SO linguistics whether there's been any reliable research on this.